# Capture the output of sh command in the declarative Jenkins pipeline

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In the following code I'm trying to assign the 'ls -l /' result to the `b` global variable but, when I try to print what's inside it, the result is `null.`

How can I set a global variable?

```
def b = [:]
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                script{
                    b = sh 'ls -l /'
                    println "b:"+b
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the result:

```
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -l /
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 18 11:49 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    6 Oct 20 10:40 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  360 Jan 21 10:00 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   77 Jan 21 10:00 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    6 Oct 20 10:40 home
drwxr-xr-x   8 root root   96 Jan 18 11:49 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root   34 Jan 18 11:49 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    6 Dec 26 00:00 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    6 Dec 26 00:00 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    6 Dec 26 00:00 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 276 root root    0 Jan 21 10:00 proc
drwx------   1 root root   76 Feb 12 17:32 root
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   21 Jan 21 10:00 run
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jan 18 11:49 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root    6 Dec 26 00:00 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Feb  6 02:34 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Feb 13 15:18 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   32 Dec 26 00:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root   39 Jan 21 10:00 var
[Pipeline] echo
b:null
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

As you can see the `b` variable is always set to `null`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to capture the output of [`sh` step](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) correctly then you need to replace

```
b = sh 'ls -l /'
```

with

```
b = sh script: 'ls -l /', returnStdout: true
```

The default behavior of `sh` step is that it prints the result to the console, so if you want to change its behavior you need to explicitly set `returnStdout` parameter to `true`.